# Unwrapping t.co link that links to bit.ly

Tags: python, twitter, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the URL that has been already shortened by bit.ly and again by twitter. I have already tried:

```
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
r.url
```

Also by using libraries such as [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/).

All these solutions would work if i wanted the final destination for the t.co link, however, I do need the intermediate shortener, which I now I can get via a HEAD request but I can't get Python 3 http.client working in order to get the location. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> c = http.client.HTTPConnection('t.co')
>>> c.request('GET', '/7fGoazTYpc')          # or HEAD, but body is empty anyway
>>> r = c.getresponse()
>>> r.getheader('Location')
'http://bit.ly/900913'
```

Answer (score 1):

`requests` automatically follows redirects, but it lets you access all URLs via the `history` attribute.

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://bit.ly/UG4ECS')
>>> r.url
u'http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/exo'
>>> r.history
(<Response [301]>,)
>>> r.history[0].url
u'http://bit.ly/UG4ECS'
>>>
```